# Kusto nested let statement

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

Is there a way to have a nested `let` statement in Kusto (KQL)? The solution below didn't work for me.

```
let GetData = (ReportingDatabase: string, IdleDetectDatabase: string, ScaleUnit: string)
{
let wv_entity = cluster(ReportingDatabase).database('Report').WorkspaceEntity_MV;
let dv_entity = cluster(ReportingDatabase).database('Report').DeviceEntity_MV;
let TimeScale = "7d";
let unique_devices = (
    cluster(IdleDetectDatabase).database("idledetect").DailyHibernateResumeComparisonByDevice_Snapshot
    | where UsageDate > ago(totimespan(TimeScale))
    | where IsPredicted == true);
    let TimeScale_7 = 
        cluster(IdleDetectDatabase).database("idledetect").DailyRDAgentHROutofwindowLoginPerDevice_Snapshot
        | where UsageDate > ago(totimespan(TimeScale))
        | summarize 
            day_1= countif(device_count >=1),
            day_2= countif(device_count >=2),
            day_3= countif(device_count >=3),
            day_4 = countif(device_count >=4),
            day_5 = countif(device_count >=5),
            day_6 = countif(device_count >=6),
            day_7 = countif(device_count >=7);
    TimeScale_7
};
union
    GetData('clusterna01.eastus.kusto.windows.net', 'clusterna01.eastus.kusto.windows.net', 'PRNA01'),
    GetData('clusterna02.centralus.kusto.windows.net', 'clusterna02.centralus.kusto.windows.net', 'PRNA02'),
    GetData('clustereu01.northeurope.kusto.windows.net', 'clustereu01.northeurope.kusto.windows.net', 'PREU01'),
    GetData('clustereu02.westeurope.kusto.windows.net', 'clustereu02.westeurope.kusto.windows.net', 'PREU02'),
    GetData('clusterap01.southeastasia.kusto.windows.net', 'clusterap01.southeastasia.kusto.windows.net', 'PRAP01'),
    GetData('clusterau01.australiaeast.kusto.windows.net', 'clusterau01.australiaeast.kusto.windows.net', 'PRAU01')
```

I am asking that, because "inside" the `TimeScale_7` I can change the query in any way I want and then use the `union` operator later.

So, I would like to merge the results of the query above with the SAME query, but the summarization will be like the one below, when     `let TimeScale = "15d";`, for example:

```
| summarize 
    day_1= countif(device_count >=1),
    day_2= countif(device_count >=2),
    day_3= countif(device_count >=3),
    day_4 = countif(device_count >=4),
    day_5 = countif(device_count >=5),
    day_6 = countif(device_count >=6),
    day_7 = countif(device_count >=7),
    day_8 = countif(device_count >=8),
    day_9 = countif(device_count >=9),
    day_10 = countif(device_count >=10),
    day_11 = countif(device_count >=11),
    day_12 = countif(device_count >=12),
    day_13 = countif(device_count >=13),
    day_14 = countif(device_count >=14),
    day_15 = countif(device_count >=15);
```

The same will happen for "30d", the summarization will increase.
So at the end, I want ONE output. But I cannot add the TimeScale in the `GetData` function because the summarization needs to be calculated as example above.

Comment: Apologies, I don't think I am understanding your question entirely.  Would something like this work though?

let TimeScale = ago(30d);
let TimeScale_30 = cluster(IdleDetectDatabase).database("idledetect").DailyHibernateResumeComparisonByDevice_Snapshot
  | where UsageDate > (TimeScale);

Comment: @GyptheCat I just updated my question with the requirements of our problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will give error because the `unique_devices` was not declared.

[image]

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/letstatement#using-nested-let-statements),

Nested let statements are not supported like yours. You can use scalar value defined using one let in another let like below.

```
let TimeScale = "700d";
let TimeScale_30 = a| where UsageDate > ago(totimespan(TimeScale));
TimeScale_30
```

[image]

You can change the query in second let statement as per your requirement and if you want to use union, you can use it on the `TimeScale_30` which is a table.

Comment: I think that way will not work, you removed one `let` but I am using in the next `let` statement in my query as a join. And then I need the same query times 3, but I will change the summarization. I updated my question will the real requirements.